# Gdx.files.internal won't work (blueJ)

Tags: java, image, file, libgdx, bluej

I am trying to make the HelloWorldImage example from Beginning **Java** Development with **Libgdx** but I can't get the project to read the image.

This is what the project directory and first class looks like:

[image: this]

And this is the error I get when I try to run the program:

[image: this]

Comment: it seems you dont have a google jar dependency in your classpath

Comment: blueJ is an IDE, developed mainly for educational purposes. Use other IDE for development.

Answer (score 2):

I also used "Beginning Java Game Development with LibGDX" to learn LibGDX, so I know you are using BlueJ because that's what the book does. You definitely can build LibGDX games with BlueJ: the author uses it to develop dozens of games in the book. That said, the other commenters are correct: BlueJ is an "educational IDE" arguably suitable for learning Java. You could consider using a different IDE, especially if you already know Java.

[The book's source code is available for download on GitHub](https://github.com/Apress/beg-java-game-dev-w-libgdx). Download and extract the "978-1-4842-1501-2_Ch01_code.zip" archive and see how the project files are supposed to be arranged. If you compare your project to the source, it looks like you're missing the "+libs" folder which should contain gdx.jar, gdx-backend-lwjgl.jar, gdx-backend-lwjgl-natives.jar, and gdx-natives.jar. I know the author described several ways these dependencies could be installed, so perhaps you have used an alternative method, but I recommend you use the structure you find on GitHub to ensure it's working.

(If you want to use a different IDE like Netbeans or Eclipse but don't want to use LibGDX's Gradle build tool, I wrote a [short Maven pom file](http://www.sharpe.link/libgdx-maven/) that can be used to build the LibGDX games in the book.)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have libGDX's dependencies (i.e. libGDX libraries etc.) included in your program's classpath.

<strike>I don't think BlueJ even *has* an option to use dependencies.</strike> Use [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/), [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/) or [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), the [only 3 officially supported IDEs for libGDX (and the most commonly used)](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Setting-up-your-Development-Environment-(Eclipse,-Intellij-IDEA,-NetBeans)).

Edit: [You can add your libraries in a folder called `+libs` in the BlueJ project directory](http://www.bluej.org/faq.html#faq_How_do_I_use_custom_class_libraries__JARs__).

I would not recommend using BlueJ - BlueJ is, IMO, often used for teaching Java concepts (because of its object visualizer etc.) but has an extremely limited feature set.

Also, BlueJ Gradle integration doesn't exist (a useful tool for development in general.)

Instructions for setting up libGDX with these 3 IDEs are available [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Setting-up-your-Development-Environment-(Eclipse,-Intellij-IDEA,-NetBeans)).